# Calling C functions from C++ constexpr functions

Tags: c++, c, gcc, constexpr

I'm porting a project from one build system to another, but using the same compiler (gcc 4.9, using C++14). I just came across an oddity involving `constexpr` in C++ that I can't explain, and I was hoping somebody would be able to help me out.

I have a function that looks like this:

```
#include <strings.h>
constexpr uint8_t idToIndex(Id id) {
  return ffs(static_cast<std::underlying_type_t<Id>>(id)) - 1;
}
```

(where `Id` is just some enum type). This was very happy as a `constexpr` function with the old build system. However, the same function with the new build system complains about being `constexpr` because of the use of `ffs` from `strings.h`.

This makes some sense to me. After all, C doesn't have `constexpr` and `ffs` is a C function from a C header. What I don't understand is why this ever worked in the first place?

It's perhaps possible that either the old or the new build system (more likely the old) are picking up versions of system headers they shouldn't, so the two builds are seeing different `strings.h` files. It's very likely that there are slight differences in the build flags in each case. I'm absolutely certain they're both using the same compiler.

If anybody knows, what I'd like to know is:

- Why might the first build have worked where the second doesn't?
- Under what circumstances will `gcc` allow you to treat a C function as `constexpr` in C++ code?

Comment: As far as I know C doesn't have `constexpr` functions so it's not possible to called them from a `constexpr` function. However, is it possible `ffs` is just a macro on your first build system?

Comment: Multiple options. ffs might be a macro in one system, and compiler intrinsic in another. Try to find what it is, using `-E` as an argument to compiler.